# Is there any DSYM file for .framework (besides app)?

Tags: objective-c

I am a new guy in OC programming. Now I am involved in a framework development project. 
I know the framework works as a library, which contains a group of methods. It's not an application that can run on devices. 
Actually, our framework will work with customer's application. We want to investigate what happened inside our framework when customer's application crashed. **So I want the 'DSYM' file of our framework, instead of an application**.
As far as I know any iOS application does have corresponded 'DSYM',  but **I didn't find the 'DSYM' of our framework**.

Does iOS framework project have 'DSYM'? If it does have, how can I obtain it?
By the way, I am using **Xcode 8.1**.
Thanks!

Comment: is it dysm? or DSYM? Pls confirm ?

Comment: looks like each iOS framework (or call it dynamic lib) has own DSYM. I can get DSYM of my app, but I don't know how to get it from my framework. If anyone could tell me the steps to obtain DSYM from a iOS framework, I will be very glad! I am using Xcode8.1

Answer (score 4):

According to my observations, **.dSYM** files are generated for iOS dynamic framework built with *Release* configuration only.

After build succeeds, the debug symbols files can be found at these paths, for a device and simulator, respectively:

```
<Build_Root>/build/Release-iphoneos/<Product_Name>.framework.dSYM 
<Build_Root>/build/Release-iphonesimulator/<Product_Name>.framework.dSYM
```

, where

`<Build_Root>` is usually a subdirectory within `Derived Data` directory;

`<Product_Name>`is the name of your framework.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can generate dSYMs for dynamic frameworks. There are a few relevant build settings that control whether and where these files are generated:

```
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf-with-dsym,
DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH = "$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)",
DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME = "$(PRODUCT_NAME).dSYM"
```

Obviously, you can set these to whatever you want, either in your project's build settings in Xcode (the `project.pbxproj` file) or as arguments to `xcodebuild` (depending on how you generate your framework).

Answer (score -2):

DSYM (Debugging SYMbols) files generally store the debugging symbols for your app. And if app crash any where symbols replaced with appropriate method name so that it could help developer in a readable form. And for that you can use the crash log and they can be find in the iPhone where the app is installed. Each app and device have their own crash log.

Also please check this link it might help you.

[Read Crash Report](http://noverse.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-deal-with-an-iphone-crash-report/)

[Upload Symbols for iOS Framework](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/upload-symbols-for-ios-frameworks/25744)

Hopefully these might help you or guide in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for Ballu's response! According to the 'Upload Symbols for iOS Framework', I think frameworks (or call them as dynamic libs) do have DSYM files. So my question is: how can I obtain the DSYM of my framework? I can get DSYM of my app, but I don't know how to get it from my framework.

Comment: Okay, First you have to create the archive for your app which is having your framework. Onward Right Click on your archive -> Show in Finder -> Right click on file and click on Show package contents, will find your .dSYM file there in package.

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work. The target of my project is a framework. I did the archive successfully (XCode prompted succeeded), but I went to /Users/<user name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/<Today_Date>, I saw many .xcarchive folders. I found the .xcarchive of my framework, but its size is Zero bytes. I tried my other apps, they work fine and generated good .xcarchive files. Do you know why the size of the xcarchive of my framework is ZERO?

Comment: When you finished up making your framework final. Just create a demo app and then embed that framework in that app and then try to put a archive. And see if you can see file in app's archive

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes. I linked my framework with another app, I got the DSYM file of that app after archive was done. Does it mean iOS doesn't generate DSYM for framework project? DSYM is only available for app? My customer's app will link to my framework, so if their app crash, how can they use my DSYM which generated from my demo app?

Comment: Archive is the process by which you get the DSYM file. And its usually provide from apple for before app distribution for developer. And as we know a framework can't be uploaded at stores. But it could be available in other forms like PODS. And for reading Dsym file you need to learn how to read crash log and debug dsym file. There are lots of forms will be available on apple site and over internet. Please start doing so if you stuck any where you always have the stackoverflow. :)

Comment: @Ballu, excuse me, sir, you didn't read Tyler properly. He said that he can't find debug symbols files ( dsym, actually ) for embedded frameworks. It is not his trouble that he has a gap in knowledge about platform or so. Pods ( what? pods is a dependencies manager, not a platform ) take care of dsyms and put them in Archive/dsyms directory. But if you build an application with embedded frameworks, dsyms for them are not here. That is what Tyler tries to find out.